How to control one Unreal character with two controllers?
I'm trying to make a proof of concept game that allows the character to be able to be controlled by both players at once: the first player controls movement while the second controls camera and shooting.
I have it working with keyboard and mouse and gamepad with one camera and one character. I want the ability to control the character with two gamepads, and that is where I am running into problems. I cannot set the gamepads to separate channels to differentiate the controls between the two. How would I go about this?
If I set my secondary input mapping context to 1 instead of 0 it looks for another player, but I only want the one. The controls also only look for names for certain gamepads, so I can't differentiate it there either: it finds it as Generic.
Any info on the subject would be appreciated. All search results I could find ended up with trying to replicate it over a network, but I am doing it all on one screen, like a couch co op style game.
I am using Unreal version 5.4.4 at the moment with blueprints. It is a 3rd person game with only the one character. So far I've been able to have input mapping context for controls 1 and 2 by using keyboard for controller 1 and gamepad for controller 2. This works by splitting the controls between the two. In my character controller blueprint I'm then calling the Player1Look and setting that up. Same for Player2Look if the second player is playing as the camera controller instead. The same goes for all other inputs, but in the input mapping context, both are being directed towards controller 0. Which I cannot get it to work any other way at the time.
